# Email availibilty check using Ajax jQuery and codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to check email availibility using jQuery+Ajax Codeigniter problem i am facing my loader image is not loading which should load during availibilty checking process
my js file code

```
$(document) . ready(function(){
    $("#email_address").change(function(){
        var email = $("#email_address").val();
        $("#availability_email").html("<img src='<?php echo base_url();?>Images/loader.gif' align='absmiddle'>&nbsp;...");
        $.ajax({ //starting ajax request
            type: "POST",
            url: "user/check_email_registered",
            data: "email_address="+ email,
            success: function(emailtest){
                if(emailtest==0){
                    $("#availability_email"). html("<img src='<?php echo base_url();?>Images/notavailable.png'>Email Not Registered");
                }else{  
                    $("#availability_email"). html("<img src='<?php echo base_url();?>Images/available.png'>Yes! you can send reset link on this address!");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

my view file registration_view.php code snippet and ofcourse I've included js files in head section of my view file

```
<label for="email_address">Your Email:</label>
  <?php echo form_error('email_address','<div class="error">', '</div>');?>
  <input type="text" id="email_address" name="email_address" value="<?php echo set_value('email_address'); ?>" /><span id="availability_email"></span>
  </p>
```

my controller part

```
public function check_email_registered()
{
    $get_result = $this->user_model->check_email_registered();
    if(!$get_result)
        {
            echo 'Email Already in user';
        }  else {

            echo 'Email available';
        }
```

my model part

```
public function check_email_registered()
        {
            $email = $this->input->post('email_address');
            $check_for_email = "SELECT * FROM SYSTEM_USERS WHERE Email= $email AND Activation 0";
            $result = $this->db->query($check_for_email);
            if($result->num_rows() > 0)
            {
                return FALSE;
            }else
    return TRUE;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First i see a problem in evaluation of your javascript.

```
        success: function(emailtest){
            if(emailtest==0){
                $("#availability_email"). html("<img src='<?php echo base_url();?>Images/notavailable.png'>Email Not Registered");
            }else{  
                $("#availability_email"). html("<img src='<?php echo base_url();?>Images/available.png'>Yes! you can send reset link on this address!");
            }
        }
```

AND

`check_email_registered()` return always a string so (emailtest == 0) is FALSE in every case

Second the query is wrong:

```
$check_for_email = "SELECT * FROM SYSTEM_USERS WHERE Email= $email AND Activation 0";
```

Activation 0 (must be) Activation = 0

If your problem persist provide more information about error use inspector of Chrome or Firefox!

**UPDATE**
Another problem

data: "email_address="+ email,

must be a json object

data:{"email_address": email}

Comment: I corrected my query and its resulting in the same way u mentioned, please advice what should I do to get the desired results

Comment: You had change the code for your condition of javascript
if(!$get_result){ echo 'Email Already in user'; } 
else { echo 'Email available'; }
TO
if(!$get_result){ echo 1; } 
else { echo 0; }

Comment: I did it now but still the same result furthermore the loader image i want to display is not displaying if I see the URL of the image it says "http://localhost/don/user/images/loader.gif" instead it should be "http://localhost/don/images/loader.gif" what is wrong with my js file please advice waiting

Comment: check your config if your $config["base_url"] is set correctly and try to make a test to add ../ before images/loader.gif if the base_url is right.

Comment: $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/don/'; if I change it to
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/don/user'; all of my styles are and js files are gone as they are placed under don/jQuery , don/css also don/images

Comment: I leave empty usually $config['base_url'] = ""; bcs i consider that a root and you can decide to use one folder assets or media to put file css and js. And you are four sure that the path of all media file script image css is always "<?=base_url("assets")?>/<css\/img> or <script>"